# Should the programming language be Turing-Complete?

Tags: discussion

The question appeared on chat. For the *Hello, world!* problem `Uryyb, jbeyq!` is a solution in rot13, but rot13 is not a general purpose language. Should these languages be allowed?

Comment: I think I may have even given that answer before it came up in chat :) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world/311#311

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should answers to fixed-output challenges be written in a programming language?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/should-answers-to-fixed-output-challenges-be-written-in-a-programming-language) (Another plausible dupe target would be  [Do submissions have to be answered with a programming language?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/do-submissions-have-to-be-answered-with-a-programming-language?rq=1), but I can't vote to double-dupe on Meta as I don't have a dupehammer here.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we need to over regulate here. The answer does slip past 2 of the 3 conditions already imposed by the question.

The simple fix is to ask slightly harder questions.

Probably it's a good idea to aim in say the 40-100 char range for the best perl/golfscript/ruby/python answers when you compose a question.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, the answer could be written as a bash script that includes the `rot13` call. So it's tricky to eliminate any such answers and it'll be hard to police. I think that the community will do the appropriate job of voting these answers up/down based on how sensible they are.

So until a really inappropriate language comes up my vote is yes, they should be allowed.

Comment: I thought about solving that task with Word field functions. Alas the only way to get a character is to use `SYMBOL` which, again, violates two rules :-(