# Can I answer in a microcontroller programming language?

Tags: discussion

I study electronics, and from time to time we use microcontrollers and have an emulator program to test the code with inputs and outputs to see the result.

Would this form of coding be allowed? If so, what files would I have to upload (and to where) to allow use of it? This language would probably only be used for numerical problems as it only operates in 8 bit binary / 2 bit hex.

Comment: Highly related, possible dupe: [What are programming languages?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073)  [Another one regarding answering with programming languages.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/do-submissions-have-to-be-answered-with-a-programming-language?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Absolutely

Any language is acceptable given two conditions:

- It has an accessible method to run it
- It can be counted in bytes

The first rule does include micro controllers and other hardware, as long as it can be purchased, but an online emulator is preferred, as only free languages may compete in Cops vs Robbers challenges.

The second rule means you need a method to count how big an uploaded program is, in this case, 8 bits is just a byte, so each binary number or two hex digits would be one byte.

All you need to supply is the name of the micro controller, and any programs you need to load into it.