# Can I use Power Query "M" Language - and what should it be called?

Tags: discussion, languages

I enjoy using Power Query "M" language ([Microsoft Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/power-query-m-reference))

Is this language permitted - and in cases where the language name is to be used, should this be referred to as `M`, `Power Query`, `Power Query M Language` or something else?

Comment: I don't think it matters, just link to it's page somewhere in your answer because I'm sure no one's heard of it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>As long as the language you mean to use falls into [PPCG's definition of a programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073), you're free to use it.</s>

As Nathan pointed out, PPCG [doesn't even require you to answer in a programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/20198), so yes, feel free to use whatever language you like.

Regarding what you should call it, there's no specific answer to that. As Pavel suggested, you can just use the name you feel is appropriate and link to the language's official page.

Comment: [We don't actually require answers to use a language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/20198)