# Sandbox instructions for new users

Tags: discussion, sandbox, new-users

We now have a [nifty new info-box to point new users to the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18028/an-info-box-to-point-new-users-to-the-sandbox). Hooray!

[image: CGSE info box]

But when a new user does go to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/20260) for the first time, the instructions there don't give them much to work from to write their Sandboxed challenge. I think the Sandbox post itself is prime real estate for challenge-writing guidance and links that users might actually read. For example, it think it would help to mention:

- [Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges)
- Writing test cases
- How long to Sandbox for (the linked [Sandbox FAQ](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056/20260) includes this but is too hidden I think)

What can we put in the Sandbox post to make it more immediately useful for new challenge writers?

Comment: Some other old meta posts that may contain relevant info (or might be worth linking from some point in the new sandbox wording):

Comment: [Unspoken challenge rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9022/unspoken-challenge-rules?r=SearchResults)

Comment: [Things to consider when creating a challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/things-to-consider-when-creating-a-challenge?r=SearchResults)

Comment: I'm going to comment on top of my up-vote, I made my first sandbox post less than 1 week ago and I literally missed all these information! I just went with what I had learned over time. This suggestion is a must for new users.

Comment: @Night2 Might you be interested in writing down some of the useful knowledge you learned over time in an answer?

Comment: @xnor, I'm not the right person for this, I have not a single posted challenge yet. What I have learned over time is what I have seen in different challenges and necessarily isn't the right/correct idea. I probably will update my sandbox as well based on some items I have read in **"Things to avoid when writing challenges"**.

Comment: It would be better that there is a template provided for new users to write new challenges. They need to make sure every mandatory field in the template is provided.