# Should the Language of the Month post be an "Upcoming event"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, language-of-the-month

Some sites on the network have an additional sidebar box for "Upcoming Events", which is separate from both the "Featured on Meta" and "Host Meta Posts" boxes:

[image] [image]

Screenshots taken from [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) and [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions). Despite the name, this also includes events currently in progress.

I think this would be a good thing to use for our [Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-of-the-month) event. It would free up one of the three [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) slots, and would allow for more questions to be shown in the "Hot Meta Questions" bar, promoting more meta engagement.

<s>Unfortunately, I can't find any information about *how* to set up an "Upcoming Events" box. I'd expect that we'd need to get a CM to set this up for us, similar to our [info box](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18028/66833), which might require more work from them than is justified for this.</s> According to [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino), [mods are able to do this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57796649#57796649), so this should be fairly trivial to set up if we do want it

Thoughts?

Comment: wait, this is a thing? :D i think this would make some sense, though at the same time, the current LOTM makes sense to be featured for the entire month so people know to look into using that language. then again, maybe it makes sense for it to just be an upcoming event for the whole month scheduled for the end of the month

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Yeah, this would just be a slight "moving around" of where in the sidebar the post is, so that more meta posts can be shown there as well. The LotM posts would still be up there for the full month (I think events can go for that long, but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes

LotM is indeed an event with a defined period, and if being an event does free up one slot for featured/hot meta posts, why not :)